# Formating timestamp in readable time format (days since into correct 360 day Calendar)

Tags: r, time-series, chron

I have the following problem. I've got model data between the years 2006 and 2100, but every month has 30 days, that means the calendar format is 360_day. Is there the possibility, to change the calendar format in chron into this format? "This format" means, that I have 30 days for each month. With the method below, chron uses the normal calendar format.

The transformed timestamp starts at (12/Mar/2005 12:00:00) instead of the correct (1/Jan/2006 12:00:00) and uses the normal calendar format, which you can see, when you try out the code and use the subset.

```
time.reconf <- chron(time, origin = c(12, 1, 1949),format = c(dates = "dd/mm/yyyy", times = "h:m:s"))
```

the following data is a subset of time:

```
 structure(c(20190.5, 20191.5, 20192.5, 20193.5, 20194.5, 20195.5, 
 20196.5, 20197.5, 20198.5, 20199.5, 20200.5, 20201.5, 20202.5, 
 20203.5, 20204.5, 20205.5, 20206.5, 20207.5, 20208.5, 20209.5, 
 20210.5, 20211.5, 20212.5, 20213.5, 20214.5, 20215.5, 20216.5, 
 20217.5, 20218.5, 20219.5, 20220.5, 20221.5, 20222.5, 20223.5, 
 20224.5, 20225.5, 20226.5, 20227.5, 20228.5, 20229.5, 20230.5, 
 20231.5, 20232.5, 20233.5, 20234.5, 20235.5, 20236.5, 20237.5, 
 20238.5, 20239.5, 20240.5, 20241.5, 20242.5, 20243.5, 20244.5, 
 20245.5, 20246.5, 20247.5, 20248.5, 20249.5, 20250.5, 20251.5, 
 20252.5, 20253.5, 20254.5, 20255.5, 20256.5, 20257.5, 20258.5, 
 20259.5, 20260.5, 20261.5, 20262.5, 20263.5, 20264.5, 20265.5, 
 20266.5, 20267.5, 20268.5, 20269.5, 20270.5, 20271.5, 20272.5, 
 20273.5, 20274.5, 20275.5, 20276.5, 20277.5, 20278.5, 20279.5, 
 20280.5, 20281.5, 20282.5, 20283.5, 20284.5, 20285.5, 20286.5, 
 20287.5, 20288.5, 20289.5, 20290.5, 20291.5, 20292.5, 20293.5, 
 20294.5, 20295.5, 20296.5, 20297.5, 20298.5, 20299.5, 20300.5, 
 20301.5, 20302.5, 20303.5, 20304.5, 20305.5, 20306.5, 20307.5, 
 20308.5, 20309.5, 20310.5, 20311.5, 20312.5, 20313.5, 20314.5, 
 20315.5, 20316.5, 20317.5, 20318.5, 20319.5, 20320.5, 20321.5, 
 20322.5, 20323.5, 20324.5, 20325.5, 20326.5, 20327.5, 20328.5, 
 20329.5, 20330.5, 20331.5, 20332.5, 20333.5, 20334.5, 20335.5, 
 20336.5, 20337.5, 20338.5, 20339.5, 20340.5, 20341.5, 20342.5, 
 20343.5, 20344.5, 20345.5, 20346.5, 20347.5, 20348.5, 20349.5, 
 20350.5, 20351.5, 20352.5, 20353.5, 20354.5, 20355.5, 20356.5, 
 20357.5, 20358.5, 20359.5, 20360.5, 20361.5, 20362.5, 20363.5, 
 20364.5, 20365.5, 20366.5, 20367.5, 20368.5, 20369.5, 20370.5, 
 20371.5, 20372.5, 20373.5, 20374.5, 20375.5, 20376.5, 20377.5, 
 20378.5, 20379.5, 20380.5, 20381.5, 20382.5, 20383.5, 20384.5, 
 20385.5, 20386.5, 20387.5, 20388.5, 20389.5, 20390.5, 20391.5, 
 20392.5, 20393.5, 20394.5, 20395.5, 20396.5, 20397.5, 20398.5, 
 20399.5, 20400.5, 20401.5, 20402.5, 20403.5, 20404.5, 20405.5, 
 20406.5, 20407.5, 20408.5, 20409.5, 20410.5, 20411.5, 20412.5, 
 20413.5, 20414.5, 20415.5, 20416.5, 20417.5, 20418.5, 20419.5, 
 20420.5, 20421.5, 20422.5, 20423.5, 20424.5, 20425.5, 20426.5, 
 20427.5, 20428.5, 20429.5, 20430.5, 20431.5, 20432.5, 20433.5, 
 20434.5, 20435.5, 20436.5, 20437.5, 20438.5, 20439.5, 20440.5, 
 20441.5, 20442.5, 20443.5, 20444.5, 20445.5, 20446.5, 20447.5, 
 20448.5, 20449.5, 20450.5, 20451.5, 20452.5, 20453.5, 20454.5, 
 20455.5, 20456.5, 20457.5, 20458.5, 20459.5, 20460.5, 20461.5, 
 20462.5, 20463.5, 20464.5, 20465.5, 20466.5, 20467.5, 20468.5, 
 20469.5, 20470.5, 20471.5, 20472.5, 20473.5, 20474.5, 20475.5, 
 20476.5, 20477.5, 20478.5, 20479.5, 20480.5, 20481.5, 20482.5, 
 20483.5, 20484.5, 20485.5, 20486.5, 20487.5, 20488.5, 20489.5, 
 20490.5, 20491.5, 20492.5, 20493.5, 20494.5, 20495.5, 20496.5, 
 20497.5, 20498.5, 20499.5, 20500.5, 20501.5, 20502.5, 20503.5, 
 20504.5, 20505.5, 20506.5, 20507.5, 20508.5, 20509.5, 20510.5, 
 20511.5, 20512.5, 20513.5, 20514.5, 20515.5, 20516.5, 20517.5, 
 20518.5, 20519.5, 20520.5, 20521.5, 20522.5, 20523.5, 20524.5, 
 20525.5, 20526.5, 20527.5, 20528.5, 20529.5, 20530.5, 20531.5, 
 20532.5, 20533.5, 20534.5, 20535.5, 20536.5, 20537.5, 20538.5, 
 20539.5, 20540.5, 20541.5, 20542.5, 20543.5, 20544.5, 20545.5, 
 20546.5, 20547.5, 20548.5, 20549.5, 20550.5, 20551.5, 20552.5, 
 20553.5, 20554.5, 20555.5, 20556.5, 20557.5, 20558.5, 20559.5, 
 20560.5, 20561.5, 20562.5, 20563.5, 20564.5, 20565.5, 20566.5, 
 20567.5, 20568.5, 20569.5, 20570.5, 20571.5, 20572.5, 20573.5, 
 20574.5, 20575.5, 20576.5, 20577.5, 20578.5, 20579.5), .Dim = 390L)
```

Comment: i actually don't understand it, how can every month contain 30 days (like e.g. february?

Comment: + you say :  You've data, and every month contains 30 days -->  Is there the possibility, to change the calendar format in chron into this format? <--- What do you mean with **this format**

Comment: I've got data from a model output and it calculated daily data for every month, but every month contains 30 days in this model. "This format" means, that I have 30 days for each month. The timezone is GMT+1.

Comment: - is it possible, to transform the data, first, to the unix time ? (1970)

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont think so. First time I encountered data like this and I dont understand, why a model is using such an output. I worked with alot of model outputs, but this time format is pretty unusual for me.

Comment: -Nucore, these dates  how complex are they? are they just? one day or? dus time count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed your time series into a normal vector

```
time <- c(20190.5, 20191.5, 20192.5, 20193.5, 20194.5, 20195.5, 
          20196.5, 20197.5, 20198.5, 20199.5, 20200.5, 20201.5, 20202.5, 
          20203.5, 20204.5, 20205.5, 20206.5, 20207.5, 20208.5, 20209.5,
          ... 
          20567.5, 20568.5, 20569.5, 20570.5, 20571.5, 20572.5, 20573.5, 
          20574.5, 20575.5, 20576.5, 20577.5, 20578.5, 20579.5)
```

Secondly, I've installed the **PCICt** package

```
install.packages('PCICt')
library(PCICt)
```

Here you can set the parameters on **360**

```
cal <- "360_day"
```

Set the start day, to **2006-01-01**

```
origin <- "2006-01-01"
seconds.per.day <- 60*60*24
```

And edit, the time series, If the structure, is the same as you've provided then (correct me if it is wrong), it should be correct to substract the first date, from all the other dates. thus : **[ 20190.5, 20191.5, 20192.5, 20193.5 ...]** will become **[ 0 1 2 3 ... ]** . thus, 0 is the same as 2006-01-01 and 1 is 2006-01-02 -- 2 is 2006-01-03 etc

```
ts.dat.days <- time - time[1]
origin.pcict <- as.PCICt(origin, cal)
ts.dat.pcict <- origin.pcict + (ts.dat.days * seconds.per.day)
```

print the series

```
ts.dat.pcict
  [1] "2006-01-01" "2006-01-02" "2006-01-03" "2006-01-04" "2006-01-05"
  [6] "2006-01-06" "2006-01-07" "2006-01-08" "2006-01-09" "2006-01-10"
 [11] "2006-01-11" "2006-01-12" "2006-01-13" "2006-01-14" "2006-01-15"
 [16] "2006-01-16" "2006-01-17" "2006-01-18" "2006-01-19" "2006-01-20"
 [21] "2006-01-21" "2006-01-22" "2006-01-23" "2006-01-24" "2006-01-25"
 [26] "2006-01-26" "2006-01-27" "2006-01-28" "2006-01-29" "2006-01-30"
 [31] "2006-02-01" "2006-02-02" "2006-02-03" "2006-02-04" "2006-02-05"
 [36] "2006-02-06" "2006-02-07" "2006-02-08" "2006-02-09" "2006-02-10"
 [41] "2006-02-11" "2006-02-12" "2006-02-13" "2006-02-14" "2006-02-15"
 [46] "2006-02-16" "2006-02-17" "2006-02-18" "2006-02-19" "2006-02-20"
 [51] "2006-02-21" "2006-02-22" "2006-02-23" "2006-02-24" "2006-02-25"
 [56] "2006-02-26" "2006-02-27" "2006-02-28" "2006-02-29" "2006-02-30"
 [61] "2006-03-01" "2006-03-02" "2006-03-03" "2006-03-04" "2006-03-05"
 [66] "2006-03-06" "2006-03-07" "2006-03-08" "2006-03-09" "2006-03-10"
 [71] "2006-03-11" "2006-03-12" "2006-03-13" "2006-03-14" "2006-03-15"
 [76] "2006-03-16" "2006-03-17" "2006-03-18" "2006-03-19" "2006-03-20"
 [81] "2006-03-21" "2006-03-22" "2006-03-23" "2006-03-24" "2006-03-25"
 [86] "2006-03-26" "2006-03-27" "2006-03-28" "2006-03-29" "2006-03-30"
 [91] "2006-04-01" "2006-04-02" "2006-04-03" "2006-04-04" "2006-04-05"
 [96] "2006-04-06" "2006-04-07" "2006-04-08" "2006-04-09" "2006-04-10"
[101] "2006-04-11" "2006-04-12" "2006-04-13" "2006-04-14" "2006-04-15"
[106] "2006-04-16" "2006-04-17" "2006-04-18" "2006-04-19" "2006-04-20"
[111] "2006-04-21" "2006-04-22" "2006-04-23" "2006-04-24" "2006-04-25"
[116] "2006-04-26" "2006-04-27" "2006-04-28" "2006-04-29" "2006-04-30"
[121] "2006-05-01" "2006-05-02" "2006-05-03" "2006-05-04" "2006-05-05"
[126] "2006-05-06" "2006-05-07" "2006-05-08" "2006-05-09" "2006-05-10"
[131] "2006-05-11" "2006-05-12" "2006-05-13" "2006-05-14" "2006-05-15"
[136] "2006-05-16" "2006-05-17" "2006-05-18" "2006-05-19" "2006-05-20"
[141] "2006-05-21" "2006-05-22" "2006-05-23" "2006-05-24" "2006-05-25"
[146] "2006-05-26" "2006-05-27" "2006-05-28" "2006-05-29" "2006-05-30"
[151] "2006-06-01" "2006-06-02" "2006-06-03" "2006-06-04" "2006-06-05"
[156] "2006-06-06" "2006-06-07" "2006-06-08" "2006-06-09" "2006-06-10"
[161] "2006-06-11" "2006-06-12" "2006-06-13" "2006-06-14" "2006-06-15"
[166] "2006-06-16" "2006-06-17" "2006-06-18" "2006-06-19" "2006-06-20"
[171] "2006-06-21" "2006-06-22" "2006-06-23" "2006-06-24" "2006-06-25"
[176] "2006-06-26" "2006-06-27" "2006-06-28" "2006-06-29" "2006-06-30"
[181] "2006-07-01" "2006-07-02" "2006-07-03" "2006-07-04" "2006-07-05"
[186] "2006-07-06" "2006-07-07" "2006-07-08" "2006-07-09" "2006-07-10"
[191] "2006-07-11" "2006-07-12" "2006-07-13" "2006-07-14" "2006-07-15"
[196] "2006-07-16" "2006-07-17" "2006-07-18" "2006-07-19" "2006-07-20"
[201] "2006-07-21" "2006-07-22" "2006-07-23" "2006-07-24" "2006-07-25"
[206] "2006-07-26" "2006-07-27" "2006-07-28" "2006-07-29" "2006-07-30"
[211] "2006-08-01" "2006-08-02" "2006-08-03" "2006-08-04" "2006-08-05"
[216] "2006-08-06" "2006-08-07" "2006-08-08" "2006-08-09" "2006-08-10"
[221] "2006-08-11" "2006-08-12" "2006-08-13" "2006-08-14" "2006-08-15"
[226] "2006-08-16" "2006-08-17" "2006-08-18" "2006-08-19" "2006-08-20"
[231] "2006-08-21" "2006-08-22" "2006-08-23" "2006-08-24" "2006-08-25"
[236] "2006-08-26" "2006-08-27" "2006-08-28" "2006-08-29" "2006-08-30"
[241] "2006-09-01" "2006-09-02" "2006-09-03" "2006-09-04" "2006-09-05"
[246] "2006-09-06" "2006-09-07" "2006-09-08" "2006-09-09" "2006-09-10"
[251] "2006-09-11" "2006-09-12" "2006-09-13" "2006-09-14" "2006-09-15"
[256] "2006-09-16" "2006-09-17" "2006-09-18" "2006-09-19" "2006-09-20"
[261] "2006-09-21" "2006-09-22" "2006-09-23" "2006-09-24" "2006-09-25"
[266] "2006-09-26" "2006-09-27" "2006-09-28" "2006-09-29" "2006-09-30"
[271] "2006-10-01" "2006-10-02" "2006-10-03" "2006-10-04" "2006-10-05"
[276] "2006-10-06" "2006-10-07" "2006-10-08" "2006-10-09" "2006-10-10"
[281] "2006-10-11" "2006-10-12" "2006-10-13" "2006-10-14" "2006-10-15"
[286] "2006-10-16" "2006-10-17" "2006-10-18" "2006-10-19" "2006-10-20"
[291] "2006-10-21" "2006-10-22" "2006-10-23" "2006-10-24" "2006-10-25"
[296] "2006-10-26" "2006-10-27" "2006-10-28" "2006-10-29" "2006-10-30"
[301] "2006-11-01" "2006-11-02" "2006-11-03" "2006-11-04" "2006-11-05"
[306] "2006-11-06" "2006-11-07" "2006-11-08" "2006-11-09" "2006-11-10"
[311] "2006-11-11" "2006-11-12" "2006-11-13" "2006-11-14" "2006-11-15"
[316] "2006-11-16" "2006-11-17" "2006-11-18" "2006-11-19" "2006-11-20"
[321] "2006-11-21" "2006-11-22" "2006-11-23" "2006-11-24" "2006-11-25"
[326] "2006-11-26" "2006-11-27" "2006-11-28" "2006-11-29" "2006-11-30"
[331] "2006-12-01" "2006-12-02" "2006-12-03" "2006-12-04" "2006-12-05"
[336] "2006-12-06" "2006-12-07" "2006-12-08" "2006-12-09" "2006-12-10"
[341] "2006-12-11" "2006-12-12" "2006-12-13" "2006-12-14" "2006-12-15"
[346] "2006-12-16" "2006-12-17" "2006-12-18" "2006-12-19" "2006-12-20"
[351] "2006-12-21" "2006-12-22" "2006-12-23" "2006-12-24" "2006-12-25"
[356] "2006-12-26" "2006-12-27" "2006-12-28" "2006-12-29" "2006-12-30"
[361] "2007-01-01" "2007-01-02" "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05"
[366] "2007-01-06" "2007-01-07" "2007-01-08" "2007-01-09" "2007-01-10"
[371] "2007-01-11" "2007-01-12" "2007-01-13" "2007-01-14" "2007-01-15"
[376] "2007-01-16" "2007-01-17" "2007-01-18" "2007-01-19" "2007-01-20"
[381] "2007-01-21" "2007-01-22" "2007-01-23" "2007-01-24" "2007-01-25"
[386] "2007-01-26" "2007-01-27" "2007-01-28" "2007-01-29" "2007-01-30"
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a tad late with this answer, but there is a new way of dealing with this issue.

It appears that you have a data file that is formatted using the CF Metadata Conventions time coordinate. Is this climate projection data? (It appears to me that you might have CORDEX data, given the origin of 1949-12-01 and data starting in 2006.)

Nowadays there is package [CFtime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=CFtime) on CRAN. This package can deal with all CF calendars transparently:

```
install.packages("CFtime")
library(CFtime)

# Using your example
cf <- CFtime("days from 1949-12-01", "360_day", time)

# usually you would read this straight out of your netCDF file:
nc <- nc_open("my_data_file.nc")
cf <- CFtime(nc$dim$time$units, nc$dim$time$calendar, nc$dim$time$vals)

# Get the list of dates as string...
CFtimestamp(cf)

# ... or create a factor for further processing
f <- CFfactor(cf, "month") # or day, dekad, season, year
```

This works on any of the CF calendars, including the standard one.